# spring restservice asynchronous logging functionality

Tags: spring, asynchronous, callable

I had written rest services in spring that is running perfectly fine.

Now, I need to add perform some db transactions before returning response to user.

This db transaction is independent to response retrieved.

For example,

```
@PostMapping("login")
    public TransactionResponse loginAuthentication(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequestBody loginRequest) {
        TransactionResponse transactionResponse = new TransactionResponse();
        try {
            transactionResponse = loginService.validateUser(loginRequest);

            //independent transaction needs to be executed in a separate thread
            loginSerice.addLoginLog(transactionResponse);

            //return below response without waiting to compelete above log transaction
            return transactionResponse; 
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return CommonUtils.setErrorResponse(transactionResponse, e);
        }

    }
```

I read upon async controller in spring mvc  [link](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/07/understanding-callable-and-spring-deferredresult.html). Although controller 
 executes respective functionality in a separate thread but I don't want to wait for db transaction to be completed. **After getting response from service layer, it should be forwarded to user without any delay.**

Any Suggestions !!

Spring version is 4.3

Comment: Have a look at the spring @Async annotation

Answer (score 1):

I posted this answer to help the fellow developers with same kind of requirement (to execute a void function in a separate thread).

Since I am not experienced in multithreading/asynchronous environment, I want to keep it simple by using spring asynchronous methods.

**So, First I created the Thread Pool**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class ThreadConfig {

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("WEBAPP");
        executor.initialize();

        return executor;
    }
}
```

**Then I created a service that will execute my code in a separate thread.**

```
@Async
@Service
@Transactional
public class LoggingService {

    public void logintransaction() throws Exception{ 
        System.out.println("start login loggin");

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        System.out.println("exit");
    }

}
```

**Lastly, I called the above service on my controller.** As I can see `Total Time Taken` is printed first, then "start login loggin" is printed. This means my new method is executed in a new thread.

```
@Autowired
    private LoggingService loggingService;


    @PostMapping("login")
    public TransactionResponse loginAuthentication(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequestBody loginRequest) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        TransactionResponse transactionResponse = new TransactionResponse();
        try {
            transactionResponse = loginService.validateUser(loginRequest);

            //independent transaction needs to be executed in a separate thread
            //loginSerice.addLoginLog(transactionResponse);
            loggingService.logintransaction();

            //return below response without waiting to compelete above log transaction

            System.err.println("Total Time Taken=>"+(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
            return transactionResponse; 
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return CommonUtils.setErrorResponse(transactionResponse, e);
        }

    }
```

Thanks